# Adding an object to the array React; "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Expected effect: click button -> call function `add` -> add object `this.color` to array `products`- property `colors` in component App. Example:
 `colors: [{color:" green "}, {color:" black "}]` -> `colors: [{color: "green"}, {color: "black"}, {color: "red "}]`

**Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 0, colors: [{color:"green"}, {color:"black"}], desc: "some desc" },
      { id: 1, colors: [{color:"yellow"}, {color:"purple"}], desc: "some desc1" }
    ],
    index: null
  };


  add = (newColor) => {
    let newProducts = [...this.state.products]
    newProducts[index].colors.push(newColor);
    this.setState({products: newProducts});
  }

   select = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      index: index
    })
  }


  render() {
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
            <Product
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              select={() => this.select(index)}
            />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <Details
        add={this.add}
      />
    </div>
  }
}
```

**Details**

```
class Details extends React.Component {

  click1 = () => {
      this.color = {
          color: 'red'
      }

      this.props.add(this.color);
  }



  render() {
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.click1}></button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
newProducts[this.state.index].colors.push(newColor);
```

But also, you should use the [callback pattern for setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) if you're going to set state based on previous state, so:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  let newProducts = [...prevState.products];
  newProducts[prevState.index].colors.push(newColor);
  return {products: newProducts};
});
```

Comment: Do I have to use `newProducts[prevState.index]` ? Is it necessary? Maybe it should be: `newProducts[this.state.index]` ? Look at  user Orar's answer

Comment: Calls to setState are batched, so relying on this.state.index may not be what you think it is when the update is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index` is `undefined`. So it's accessing an array element of index `undefined`.

```
 const arr = [3, 2]
 arr[undefined] === undefined // true
```

So I will

```
 add = (newColor) => {
   const { index } = this.state;

   if (index) {
     this.setState(prevState => {
       const newProducts = [...prevState.products];
       newProducts[index].colors.push(newColor);

       return { products: newProducts };
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe should be: `newProducts[prevState.index]` ?